# Audio Domain Specific Language vs Python

Tags: python, audio, dsl, supercollider

I want to write some code to do acoustic analysis and I'm trying to determine the proper tool(s) for the job. I would normally write something like this in Python using numpy and scipy and possibly Cython for the analysis part. I've discovered that the world of Python audio libraries is a bit chaotic, with scads of very limited packages in various states of development.

I've also come across a bunch of audio/acoustic specific languages like SuperCollider, Faust, etc. that seem to make the audio processing easy but may be limited in terms of IO and analysis capability.

I'm currently working on Linux with Alsa and PulseAudio installed by default. I would prefer not to involve and of the various and sundry other audio packages like Jack if possible, though that is not a hard requirement.

My primary interest in this question is to determine whether there is a domain specific language that will provide for quicker prototyping and testing or whether a general language like Python is more appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I've got a lot of experience with SuperCollider and Python (with and without Numpy). I do a lot of audio analysis, and I'm afraid the answer depends on what you want to do.

1. If you want to create systems that will input OR output audio in real time, then Python is not a good choice. The audio I/O libraries (as you say) are a bit sketchy. There's also a fundamental issue that Python's garbage collector is not really designed for realtime stuff. **You should use a system that is designed from the ground up for realtime.** SuperCollider is nice for this, and as caseyanderson notes, some of the standard building-blocks for audio analysis are right there. There are other environments too.
2. If you want to do hardcore work such as applying various machine learning algorithms, not necessarily in real time (i.e. if you can get away with reading/writing WAV files rather than live audio), then **you should use a general-purpose programming language with wide support, and an ecosystem of good libraries** for the extra things you want. Using Python with libs such as numpy and scikits-learn works great for this. It's good for quick prototyping, but not only does it lack solid realtime audio, it also has far fewer of the standard audio building-blocks. Those are two important things which hold you back when prototyping audio pipelines.

So, then, you're caught between these two options. Depending on your application you may be able to **combine the two** by manipulating the audio I/O in a realtime environment, and using **OSC messaging** or shell scripts to communicate with an external Python process. The limitation there is that you can't really throw masses of data around between the two (you can't sensibly pipe all your audio across to some other process, that'd be silly).

Answer (score 2):

SuperCollider has lots of support for things along these lines, both as externals/plugins or Quarks. That said, it depends exactly what you want to do. If you are simply looking to detect events, `Onsets.kr` would be fine. If you are looking for frequency/pitch information, `Pitch` or `Tartini` would work (I find `Tartini` to be more accurate). If you are trying to track amplitude, a combination of `Amplitude.ar` and some simple math would also work.

Similarly, there is `SpecCentroid.kr` (for a kind of brightness analysis), `Loudness.kr`, `SpecFlatness.kr`, etc.

The above are all pretty general, and there are lots more (the `JoshUGens` externals package has some interesting FFT-related acoustics stuff). So I would recommend downloading the program, joining the mailing list (if you have further questions), which lives [here](http://www.beast.bham.ac.uk/research/sc_mailing_lists.shtml), and poking around in the Externals, Quarks, and Standard UGens.

Nonetheless, since I am not sure what you are trying to do, I cannot make more concrete recommendations than the above combined with my feeling that it makes the most sense to go to SC for this, rather than writing all of your own tools in Python from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to do, but as an additional suggestion I would put forth: Spear with scripting in Common Lisp. If what you are doing involves a great deal of spectral analysis, then you can do the heavy Lifting in Spear, and script all of this using Common List with Common Music. Spear has some great tools in terms of editing out very specific partials.